# SQL update where select from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

im trying to update 1 row in a table where some values are null, and the userId is not in another row with the same groupid(there is a unique index on both of those columns)

this what i tried but i cannot select from the same table as i update:

```
update rooms 
set userId = 112, uuid = 'e42dcbd0-56fd-4cc9-8cfd-f49d089cc317', timestamp = 1664277288 
where uuid is null and userId is null and roomId = 2 and 
groupId not in (select groupId from rooms where userId = 112 and roomId = 2)
limit 1
```

Comment: Provide a sample. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: *where uuid is null and userId is null* - i.e. if only one of these columns is NULL then the row shouldn't be updated at all? or maybe this NULL must be updated nevertheless?

Comment: @Akina both of those updated at once, so i guess i can specify only 1 of those 2 columns in the where :)

Comment: Have you tried using a table alias?

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes it did not solve the issue

Comment: Then you might need to use a temporary table or a common-table expression.

Comment: Self join syntax works, just you need to use anti-join instead of subquery